# Asterisk: music on hold stuttering

Tags: asterisk

We're having issues with music on hold (moh). Occasionally (maybe every second time) a caller is put on hold and moh is played, the music is stuttering/stammering (in various degrees - sometimes you can hear the music quite well with minor interruptions, sometimes, the music is the interruption to the silence).

Our configuration:

```
Asterisk 13.7.2 inside a VM
moh: WAV mono 8000 Hz 16bit PCL
asterisk.conf: internal_timing is unset (defaults to "yes")
```

System load is low during MOH streaming, but lsof shows about 20-30 threads in the asterisk main process accessing the wav file.

No MP3 files and therefor no related plugins are used. Similar issues also happened with the "original" music on hold files.

EDIT:
It turned out, that obviously the client softphone is sending concurring RTP streams (with no sound, i.e. silence) that are mixed up somehow and thus cause the stuttering. We will likely try to downgrade the asterisk server as we have another setup that works well with asterisk 11

Comment: Did you check the load on host of VM?

Comment: concerning CPU and memory, the load on the host is also low (like 2 % for the asterisk VM)

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue with ivr prompts, there was a disk i/o issue. The customer moved the VM to an another disk, and it worked. I used to run an another problem when I used wav files as source for concanetated prompts. There was a cracking noise between the files. The solution was I had to convert prompts to Asterisk's native format (SLN16), with the following settings in Goldwave: RAW, PCM signed 16bit, little endian, 16KHz, mono. May you can use ramdisk for the moh files, there is no disk i/o virtually...

Comment: I don't think it's file-related as the same file play perfectly well as queue or voicemail files.

Answer (score 0):

This may be codec related - which codec is the channel using?  Other than ulaw/alaw you will likely get stutter.

Comment: I don't think its related to the codec. Other files that are created the same way work for voicemail, queues, etc.

Comment: I would check transcoding too - if this happens only to outside callers.  Still possibly a codec issue - even if sometimes its ok.

Comment: According to `sip show channels` its `ulaw`. Interestingly, after the call is back from hold ("unholded"), the format is `ulaw|h264`.

Comment: Is this an android client (perhaps video phone app)?  Something is renegotiating the codecs.  Force the codec (deny all but ulaw) as a test.

Comment: No, it's Jitsi (latest stable) on Windows 7. I already forced all codecs that are supported (ulaw, alaw and gsm). No difference. I already found out that other softphones work. I'm in correspondence with the jitsi mailing list about the issue.

Comment: In that case start debugging jitter.  (Lots of posts on that).  Causes range from Asterisk config to hardware throughput.